# How to list on a webpage, all the fonts installed on your machine?

Tags: javascript, php, css

I'm wondering which is the best approach to show all the fonts available on someone machine, and display them on a web page.

There is an example out there that does that www.wordmark.it

I'm wondering if they have a list of say 50K fonts and they go through each one to check if the font can be displayed or there is another magic to do that?

Comment: that site is just guessing what might be installed, there's no real way to do this, and certainly not with php

Comment: You would need access to someone's harddrive in order to know what they have or don't have installed on their machine. You can get hard drive permissions if you have an app on the app stores, but I don't think there's any way you can do that in a chrome browser.